# AWS EKS - Create Load Balancer Service throws out of service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I have a quick question regarding AWS EKS that whenever I create a K8s service with of type LoadBalancer, it provisions a classic ELB backed the EC2 where services are running. Now whenever I try to hit the Load Balancer ELB from the Internet, it returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error. If I navigate back to ELB and look at the instances behind ELB, it shows the status of EC2 instances as OutOfService.

This happens either I use my own K8s deployments & services or the one provided with documentation. Anyone can help me with this? More over, is there any way to provision a different type of Load Balancer for a K8s service? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: I have created my EKS cluster with terraform. On that cluster, I had this issue. But when I created a cluster with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html manually, it works with no issue.

Comment: Same here. I followed the same steps mentioned in the documentation on Terraform website for EKS and it worked. It seems like we're missing the tag name (EKS Cluster Name) assign to the subnet in the Terraform configuration file.

Comment: After deleting some load balancer services and applying them again, ELB health checks failed again on the cluster which was created manually (i.e. without terraform)

Comment: I'm working for creating a Terraform Module for EKS. I'll update on the registry when it's ready.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this is with a cluster created through the aws docs listed by @Younghan. It is pointing at a deployment.

Comment: Maybe I found a solution: To create or apply a load balancer type service for a deployment, you should set spec.ports with name, port, targetPort, nodePort and protocol properties. (total 5 properties) And the value of targetPort should be a name of the containerPort in the deployment, not a number. e.g. http-server instead of 80. Then the health checks of ELB would work properly.

Comment: @Younghan did it work if you give those properties ?

Comment: Did you fixed this in the end? can you please help and post answer? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Kubernetes Service of type LoadBalancer, the AWS cloud provider load balancer controller creates AWS Classic Load Balancers (in-tree) by default.

Use [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) instead of the AWS cloud provider load balancer controller. The AWS Load Balancer Controller creates ELB NLB. But note that, the controller by default would create internal ELB, to create a public ELB add annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme=internet-facing` to the LoadBalancer service.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html

Answer (score -3):

This is default behavior or K8S with on cloud providers , A service type Load Balancer will spins up real one which affect cost. 
Better to use K8S Ingress as best practice and can use as Endpoint or you can add under External Load Balancer.